# Search if one string is substring of another string

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jquery to get data,

```
var passwordReset = {
        UserName: $("#txtLgnUsername").val(),
        Password: $("#hdnOldPassword").val(),
        NewPassword: $("#txtLgnPasswordReset").val()
    }
```

I don't want person to enter his userName as password, so I used this in next line

```
if (passwordReset.NewPassword.contains(passwordReset.UserName)) {
        alert(passwordReset.NewPassword);
        notifyMessage.showNotifyMessage('error', 'User name cannot be part of password.Please try a different password.', false);
    }
```

Which isn't helping...How do i check if my password has userName??
Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Vikrant [this is Javascript, not java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java). It is however, a duplicate of [How can I check if one string contains another substring?](How can I check if one string contains another substring?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `if` condition to

```
if(passwordReset.NewPassword.indexOf(passwordReset.UserName)>-1){..}
```

`indexOf` will return `-1` if username is not present in password. `indexOf` actually returns the position of the `substring` in the actual string and if not present, it returns `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (passwordReset.NewPassword.toLowerCase().indexOf(passwordReset.UserName.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        alert(passwordReset.NewPassword);
        notifyMessage.showNotifyMessage('error', 'User name cannot be part of password.Please try a different password.', false);
    }
```